# How to prove that f/g is bounded variation?

Tags: bounded-variation

I am trying to prove that when $f$ and $g$ are of bounded variation on $[a, b]$, $f/g$ is of bounded variation on [a, b] if there exists an $\varepsilon\gt 0$ such that $|g(x)|\ge \varepsilon$ for $x\in [a, b]$.

---

Let $\Gamma$ be a partition of $[a, b]$ by $\Gamma=\{x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_m: x_0=a, x_m=b\}$.

Let $\displaystyle S_\Gamma[f; a, b] = \sum_{i=0}^m \left[f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})\right]$.

Let $\displaystyle V[f; a, b] = \sup_{\Gamma} S_\Gamma[f; a, b]$.

\begin{align}
S_\Gamma[f/g; a, b] &= \sum_{i=1}^m \left|\frac{f(x_i)}{g(x_i)}-\frac{f(x_{i-1})}{g(x_{i-1})}\right|\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m \left| \frac{g(x_{i-1})\left(f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})\right)-f(x_{i-1})\left(g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1})\right)}{g(x_i)g(x_{i-1})} \right|\\
&\le\sum_{i=1}^m \left|\max(g)\right|\left|\frac{f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})}{g(x_i)g(x_{i-1})}\right| - \sum_{i=1}^m \left|\max(f)\right|\left|\frac{g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1})}{g(x_i)g(x_{i-1})}\right|\\
&= \left|\max(g)\right| \left|\frac{S_\Gamma[f; a, b]}{\sum_{i=1}^m g(x_i)g(x_{i-1})}\right| - \left|\max(f)\right| \left|\frac{S_\Gamma[g; a, b]}{\sum_{i=1}^m g(x_i)g(x_{i-1})}\right|\\
&\le \left|\max(g)\right| \left|\frac{V_\Gamma[f; a, b]}{\sum_{i=1}^m g(x_i)g(x_{i-1})}\right| - \left|\max(f)\right| \left|\frac{V_\Gamma[g; a, b]}{\sum_{i=1}^m g(x_i)g(x_{i-1})}\right|
\end{align}

I proved until here but I can't proceed more.

I don't know whether $\left|\frac{A}{B}\right|$ is less than or equal to, or greater than or equal to $\frac{\left|A\right|}{\left|B\right|}$

I have the following conditions from the proposition: $$V[f; a, b] < \infty \\ V[g; a, b] < \infty$$

Moreover, the other problem is when $\varepsilon$ become smaller and smaller, the value of $\frac{1}{g}$ become bigger and bigger.

Can someone give me the way to prove this proposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

It may be easier to show separately that $f,h \in BV([a,b]) \implies fh \in BV([a,b])$ and $g \in BV([a,b]) \implies 1/g \in BV([a,b]).$

For $g$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left|\frac{1}{g(x_k)} - \frac{1}{g(x_{k-1})} \right| = \sum_{k=1}^n \left|\frac{g(x_k) - g(x_{k-1})}{g(x_k)g(x_{k-1})} \right| \\ \leqslant \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \left|g(x_k) - g(x_{k-1}) \right|$$